# vue-msal could not resolve endpoints. Please check network and try again. Details: function toString() { [native code] }

Tags: javascript, vue.js, msal.js

ClientAuthError: Error: could not resolve endpoints. Please check network and try again. Details: function toString() { [native code] }
    at ClientAuthError.AuthError [as constructor] (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/msal/lib-es6/error/AuthError.js:26:28)
    at new ClientAuthError (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/msal/lib-es6/error/ClientAuthError.js:111:28)
    at Function.ClientAuthError.createEndpointResolutionError (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/msal/lib-es6/error/ClientAuthError.js:121:16)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/msal/lib-es6/UserAgentApplication.js:465:125)
VM11105:1 GET

```html
ClientAuthError: Error: could not resolve endpoints. Please check network and try again. Details: function toString() { [native code] }
    at ClientAuthError.AuthError [as constructor] (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/msal/lib-es6/error/AuthError.js:26:28)
    at new ClientAuthError (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/msal/lib-es6/error/ClientAuthError.js:111:28)
    at Function.ClientAuthError.createEndpointResolutionError (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/msal/lib-es6/error/ClientAuthError.js:121:16)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/msal/lib-es6/UserAgentApplication.js:465:125)
VM11105:1 GET https://caatdevportal.onmicrosoft.com/caatdevportal.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1a_signuporsignin/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

the config here, and no idea why

```html
Vue.use(MSAL, {
  auth: {
    clientId: "**************************",
    redirectUri: "https://localhost:44390",
    tenantId: "devportal.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_employee_test_sign",
    tenantName: "devportal.onmicrosoft.com",
    requireAuthOnInitialize: true,
    validateAuthority: false,
    onAuthentication: (ctx, error, response) => {
      console.log(response);
      console.log(ctx);
      console.log(error);
    },
    onToken: (ctx, error, response) => {
      console.log(response);
      console.log(ctx);
      console.log(error);
    },
  },
  graph: {
    callAfterInit: true,
    endpoints: {
      profile: "/me",
      photo: { url: "/me/photo/$value", responseType: "blob", force: true },
    },
  },
  request: {
    scopes: null,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I used angular, but I got the same error. Essentially login endpoint that you are targeting is not valid and it has to be in the following format:

```
https://<tenant_name>.b2clogin.com/<tenant_name>.onmicrosoft.com/<policy_name>
```

Please note that you should target `b2login.com`, not `onmicrosoft.com` for your `tenantName` :)

So in your case, I would try:

```
Vue.use(MSAL, {
  auth: {
    clientId: "**************************",
    redirectUri: "https://localhost:44390",
    tenantId: "devportal.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_employee_test_sign",
    tenantName: "devportal.b2clogin.com",
    requireAuthOnInitialize: true,
    validateAuthority: false,
    onAuthentication: (ctx, error, response) => {
      console.log(response);
      console.log(ctx);
      console.log(error);
    },
    onToken: (ctx, error, response) => {
      console.log(response);
      console.log(ctx);
      console.log(error);
    },
  },
  graph: {
    callAfterInit: true,
    endpoints: {
      profile: "/me",
      photo: { url: "/me/photo/$value", responseType: "blob", force: true },
    },
  },
  request: {
    scopes: null,
  },
});
```